# Logs are not displaying on Graylog UI (with Serilog)

Tags: .net, logging, serilog, graylog, graylog2

I am new to Graylog and trying to integrate Graylog with Serilog in my back-end app. Graylog server is on another machine and runs on 10.0.6.55. Udp port is 1514. I've did the configurations but logs are not displaying.

Here's my appsettings.json:
`"Serilog": { "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Graylog" ], "MinimumLevel": "Information", "WriteTo": [ { "Name": "Graylog", "Args": { "hostnameOrAddress": "10.0.5.57", "port": "1514", "transportType": "Udp", } } ], "Properties": { "Application": "Centralized logging application" } }`

Program.cs Log configuration part:
`Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration() .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration) .Enrich.FromLogContext() .CreateLogger();`

And here is Graylog UDP Input:
[image]

What am I missing?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You started a Raw/Plaintext UDP Input, but  Graylog sink uses the GELF format:

[GraylogSink.cs](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-graylog/blob/master/src/Serilog.Sinks.Graylog/GraylogSink.cs#L57)

Try creating a GELF input and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for response Swisstone , I've tried with UDP GELF input first, but it did not work either.